# Splitting a csv file into multiple txt. files

Tags: r, excel

I have a large csv dataset that I want to split into multiple txt files. I want the name of each file to come from the ID column and the content of each file to come from the Text column. My data looks something like this.

```
ID      Text
1       I like dogs
2       My name is
3       It is sunny
```

Would anyone be able to help advise? I don't mind using excel or R.
Thank you!

Comment: does that mean one file per row?

Comment: Yes! So a file called "1" would have the content "I like dogs"

Answer (score 3):

In R, You can `split` the data by `ID` and use `writeLines` to write it in text files.

If your dataframe is called `df`, try :

```
temp <- split(df$Text, df$ID)
Map(function(x, y) writeLines(x, paste0(y, '.txt')), temp, names(temp))
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! I got the following message " Error in writeLines(x, paste0(y, ".txt")) : 
  can only write character objects "

Comment: @Mai Seems you have `Text` column as factors. Can you run `df$Text <- as.character(df$Text)` once before running the above code.

Comment: I ran the code and didn't get any error message this time. However, in the console it just produce a list with ID and NULL below. "1 NULL, 2 NULL, 3 NULL"

Comment: Check in your working directory, there should be files with names "1.txt", "2.txt" etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of rows, this is a good task for parallel computing. ([Here's the general premise](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fast-csv-writing-for-r/): R spends a lot of time formatting the file. Writing to the disk can't be done in parallel, but formatting the file can.) So let's do it in parallel!

The `furrr` package is one of my favorites: In short, it adds parallel processing capabilities to the `purrr` package, whose map functions are quite useful. In this case, we want to use the `future_pmap` function, which lets us apply a function to each row of a dataframe. This should be all the code you need:

```r
library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess)
future_pmap(df, function(id, value) {write(value, paste0(id, ".txt"))})
```

I tested the parallel and normal versions of this function on a dataframe with 31,496 rows, and the parallel version took only 60 percent as long. This method is also about 20 percent faster than [Ronak Shah's `writeLines` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62380745/5885627).

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try next time