# How to run an lapply in parallel in R?

Tags: r, list, parallel-processing, apply, lapply

So I have tried a few different ways of doing this but each returns an a different error which is making me question if i'm even doing it correctly.

So without any parallel components, we have the following:

```
all_necks <- lapply(b_list, b_fun)
```

This works perfectly; `b_list` is a dataframe and `b_fun` is a ton of joins and functions which are to be done on the list.

Because each run takes about 5 minutes and there are 550 elements in `b_list`, I need this to be faster to be practical.

I try `future.lapply` but get the following error:

```
library(future.apply)
options(future.globals.maxSize= 178258920000)
plan(multiprocess, workers = 5) ## Parallelize using five cores
all_necks <- future_lapply(b_list, b_fun)

ERROR:
Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection
```

Then I tried `foreach` and got the following:

```
library(doParallel) 
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
all_necks <- foreach(i = 1:b_list %dopar% {b_fun})


ERROR:
There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
1: In environment() : closing unused connection 19 (<-DESKTOP-XXX)
2: In environment() : closing unused connection 18 (<-DESKTOP-XXX)
...
```

I must be doing this incorrectly but I really just want this long lapply to run faster via parallel processing.

I would prefer to do this on 5 cores.

EDIT: Session Info Added

```
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] future.apply_1.5.0  future_1.17.0       formattable_0.2.0.1 lubridate_1.7.9     data.table_1.12.8   chron_2.3-55       
 [7] Nmisc_0.3.5         anytime_0.3.7       forcats_0.5.0       stringr_1.4.0       dplyr_1.0.0         purrr_0.3.4        
[13] readr_1.3.1         tidyr_1.1.0         tibble_3.0.1        ggplot2_3.3.2       tidyverse_1.3.0     jsonlite_1.6.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6      lattice_0.20-41   listenv_0.8.0     assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.25     R6_2.4.1         
 [7] cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.1.7   reprex_0.3.0      evaluate_0.14     httr_1.4.1        pillar_1.4.4     
[13] rlang_0.4.6       readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.11   furrr_0.1.0       blob_1.2.1        rmarkdown_2.3    
[19] htmlwidgets_1.5.1 munsell_0.5.0     tinytex_0.24      broom_0.5.6       compiler_4.0.1    modelr_0.1.8     
[25] xfun_0.14         pkgconfig_2.0.3   globals_0.12.5    htmltools_0.5.0   tidyselect_1.1.0  codetools_0.2-16 
[31] fansi_0.4.1       crayon_1.3.4      dbplyr_1.4.4      withr_2.2.0       rappdirs_0.3.1    grid_4.0.1       
[37] nlme_3.1-148      gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_0.2.0   DBI_1.1.0         magrittr_1.5      scales_1.1.1     
[43] cli_2.0.2         stringi_1.4.6     fs_1.4.1          xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.1    generics_0.0.2   
[49] vctrs_0.3.1       tools_4.0.1       glue_1.4.1        hms_0.5.3         parallel_4.0.1    colorspace_1.4-1 
[55] rvest_0.3.5       knitr_1.28        haven_2.3.1
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `furrr` package? Instead of `lapply`, you would use a variant of the `map` function.

Comment: I am not familiar, but how would that help me? I would still have the issue of speed no?

Comment: The `furrr` package builds on `purrr`'s mapping functions and makes them parallel (also using `plan(multiprocess)`. I find `furrr` a lot more intuitive, so it'd be easier to avoid these errors.

Comment: Hm okay, I haven't tried that but what would I need to change for it to be implemented?

Comment: Hard for me to say without looking at your input, function, and intended output. Here's another answer I recently wrote using `future_pmap`: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62381045/5885627](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62381045/5885627).

Comment: hm okay; the input is several joins and summarizations of created variables. Each run of the lapply takes a dataframe from the list (b_list) and does all that and then returns a dataframe which has now been manipulated. So in the end I should have a list of manipulated dataframes.

Comment: I think you're looking for `furrr::future_map_dfr`.

Comment: You are on windows ?

Comment: @RémiCoulaud yessir, on windows otherwise mcapply wouldve been good.

Comment: @PrayagGordy Okay that ran but then i got this error Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what the problem is. Did you try Googling your error message? It's hard for me to diagnose this problem.

Comment: yeah so i googled and it said it could be a memory issue hence why my connectors are failing; how could we utilize the fix listed here but with furr? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503208/doparallel-error-in-r-error-in-serializedata-nodecon-error-writing-to-con

Comment: Author of the future framework here: there should be no reason for 'furrr' working better or worse that 'future.apply' here - they both are just very thin map-reduce wrappers on top of the Future API provided by the 'future' package.  They share the same weaknesses and strengths.  They basically only differ in syntax in the same way `base::lapply()` and `purrr:map()` differ.

Comment: @JohnThomas, please share your `sessionInfo()` - that's critical, minimal information needed in order to give constructive feedback and help.

Comment: @JohnThomas, you're example code on 'future.apply' uses a regular `lapply()` call - there's nothing that use parallelization in that code.

Comment: Forgot to say in my comment regarding furrr and future.apply: the same reasoning applies to using `foreach()` with the doFuture adapter - it's a thin map-reduce API on top of the Future API just like 'furrr' and 'future.apply'.

Comment: @HenrikB Added session info to OP, something is telling me it could be a memory issue ? Truly unsure; loop works perfectly as a normal lapply, but not when I want them all working in parallel.

Comment: Yes, it's likely a memory issue.  That's a lot of packages you've got loaded according to your session info.  I just wanna make sure: are all those packages need for this code (e.g. are they needed by `b_fun()`) or are some of them left-overs from trial'n'error attempts?  Related to this, when you say "`b_list` is a dataframe" - is that a `data.frame` or do you mean `data.table` (which I see in the session info).

Comment: Install the develop version of the 'future'.  It's designed to provide a bit more information on critical worker errors like this.  You can install it with `remotes::install_github("HenrikBengtsson/future@develop")`.  Restart in a fresh R session and rerun.  Hopefully, you'll get some more info when this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't `pblapply` be perfect here? It works the same as `lapply` except that you specify a cluster object. It's definitely easier to parallelize with `pblapply` on linux, since you just specify the cluster as an integer, but you can do it on Windows, too.

This is code I use when I have multiple OS types, so you only need the Windows part, but it might be helpful to see the whole `if` statement. For the Window branch, I call 2 cluster functions to set up the environment that each node would have. This involves passing any extra functions or variables, or loading up any libraries on each node.

```
numcores = 5
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
    cl = makeCluster(numcores, type = "FORK")
} else {
    cl <- makeCluster(numcores, type = "PSOCK")
    # If you're using libraries in each node, you can call this.
    clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(LibraryName)})
    clusterExport(cl, list("var1", "var2"), envir = environment())
}

out = pblapply(b_list, b_fun, cl = cl)
```